# Unable to install serialport library from npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-serialport

I face the following error while trying to install `serialport` library from `NPM`

```
$ npm i serialport

> @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 install /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp
> node-gyp-build

make: Entering directory '/home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bindings/src/serialport.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bindings/src/serialport_unix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bindings/src/poller.o
../src/poller.cpp: In static member function ‘static Napi::Object Poller::Init(Napi::Env, Napi::Object)’:
../src/poller.cpp:108:7: error: ‘class Napi::Env’ has no member named ‘SetInstanceData’
  108 |   env.SetInstanceData<Napi::FunctionReference>(constructor);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/poller.cpp:108:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  108 |   env.SetInstanceData<Napi::FunctionReference>(constructor);
      |                                              ^
../src/poller.cpp: In static member function ‘static Napi::Value Poller::New(const Napi::CallbackInfo&)’:
../src/poller.cpp:127:53: error: ‘class Napi::Env’ has no member named ‘GetInstanceData’
  127 |   Napi::FunctionReference* constructor = info.Env().GetInstanceData<Napi::FunctionReference>();
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/poller.cpp:127:92: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  127 |   Napi::FunctionReference* constructor = info.Env().GetInstanceData<Napi::FunctionReference>();
      |                                                                                            ^
../src/poller.cpp:127:94: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
  127 |   Napi::FunctionReference* constructor = info.Env().GetInstanceData<Napi::FunctionReference>();
      |                                                                                              ^
make: *** [bindings.target.mk:106: Release/obj.target/bindings/src/poller.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-71-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for serialport@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: serialport@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-delimiter@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-delimiter@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-readline@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-readline@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=14.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-cctalk@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-cctalk@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/stream@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/stream@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-inter-byte-timeout@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-inter-byte-timeout@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-regex@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-regex@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/binding-mock@10.2.2: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/binding-mock@10.2.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-ready@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-ready@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-slip-encoder@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-slip-encoder@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-spacepacket@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-spacepacket@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-byte-length@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-byte-length@11.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/bindings-interface@1.2.2: wanted: {"node":"^12.22 || ^14.13 || >=16"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/bindings-interface@1.2.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/amin/Node/serial-port/package.json'
npm WARN serial-port No description
npm WARN serial-port No repository field.
npm WARN serial-port No README data
npm WARN serial-port No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 install: `node-gyp-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/amin/.npm/_logs/2023-05-03T13_57_21_065Z-debug.log
```

I tried with `sudo` as well, but still couldn't been able to install the library.

**Node version:**

```
$ node -v
v10.19.0
```

**Npm version**

```
npm -v
6.14.4
```

**OS release:**

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Log from `/home/amin/.npm/_logs/2023-05-03T13_57_21_065Z-debug.log`

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'i', 'serialport' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v10.19.0
4 verbose npm-session ade364f099509d44
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/serialport 206ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for serialport@latest fetched in 216ms
9 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 263ms
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
13 silly install loadShrinkwrap
14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 5ms
15 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
16 silly resolveWithNewModule serialport@11.0.0 checking installable status
17 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@serialport%2fbindings-cpp 485ms (from cache)
18 silly pacote version manifest for @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 fetched in 491ms
19 silly resolveWithNewModule @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 checking installable status
20 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp-build 313ms (from cache)
21 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-addon-api 316ms (from cache)
22 silly pacote version manifest for node-gyp-build@4.6.0 fetched in 318ms
23 silly resolveWithNewModule node-gyp-build@4.6.0 checking installable status
24 silly pacote version manifest for node-addon-api@6.1.0 fetched in 321ms
25 silly resolveWithNewModule node-addon-api@6.1.0 checking installable status
26 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@serialport%2fparser-readline 600ms (from cache)
27 silly pacote version manifest for @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0 fetched in 603ms
28 silly resolveWithNewModule @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0 checking installable status
29 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@serialport%2fparser-delimiter 772ms (from cache)
30 silly pacote version manifest for @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0 fetched in 775ms
31 silly resolveWithNewModule @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0 checking installable status
32 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 1902ms
33 timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 1919ms
34 silly currentTree serial-port
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/binding-mock@10.2.2
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/bindings-interface@1.2.2
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-byte-length@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-cctalk@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-delimiter@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-inter-byte-timeout@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-packet-length@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-readline@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-ready@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-regex@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-slip-encoder@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/parser-spacepacket@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── @serialport/stream@11.0.0
34 silly currentTree ├── debug@4.3.4
34 silly currentTree └── ms@2.1.2
35 silly idealTree serial-port
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/binding-mock@10.2.2
35 silly idealTree ├─┬ @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
35 silly idealTree │ ├── @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
35 silly idealTree │ └── @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/bindings-interface@1.2.2
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-byte-length@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-cctalk@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-delimiter@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-inter-byte-timeout@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-packet-length@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-readline@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-ready@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-regex@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-slip-encoder@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/parser-spacepacket@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── @serialport/stream@11.0.0
35 silly idealTree ├── debug@4.3.4
35 silly idealTree ├── ms@2.1.2
35 silly idealTree ├── node-addon-api@6.1.0
35 silly idealTree ├── node-gyp-build@4.6.0
35 silly idealTree └── serialport@11.0.0
36 silly install generateActionsToTake
37 timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 5ms
38 silly diffTrees action count 6
39 silly diffTrees add @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
40 silly diffTrees add @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
41 silly diffTrees add node-addon-api@6.1.0
42 silly diffTrees add node-gyp-build@4.6.0
43 silly diffTrees add @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
44 silly diffTrees add serialport@11.0.0
45 silly decomposeActions action count 48
46 silly decomposeActions fetch @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
47 silly decomposeActions extract @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
48 silly decomposeActions preinstall @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
49 silly decomposeActions build @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
50 silly decomposeActions install @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
51 silly decomposeActions postinstall @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
52 silly decomposeActions finalize @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
53 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
54 silly decomposeActions fetch @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
55 silly decomposeActions extract @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
56 silly decomposeActions preinstall @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
57 silly decomposeActions build @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
58 silly decomposeActions install @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
59 silly decomposeActions postinstall @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
60 silly decomposeActions finalize @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
61 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
62 silly decomposeActions fetch node-addon-api@6.1.0
63 silly decomposeActions extract node-addon-api@6.1.0
64 silly decomposeActions preinstall node-addon-api@6.1.0
65 silly decomposeActions build node-addon-api@6.1.0
66 silly decomposeActions install node-addon-api@6.1.0
67 silly decomposeActions postinstall node-addon-api@6.1.0
68 silly decomposeActions finalize node-addon-api@6.1.0
69 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json node-addon-api@6.1.0
70 silly decomposeActions fetch node-gyp-build@4.6.0
71 silly decomposeActions extract node-gyp-build@4.6.0
72 silly decomposeActions preinstall node-gyp-build@4.6.0
73 silly decomposeActions build node-gyp-build@4.6.0
74 silly decomposeActions install node-gyp-build@4.6.0
75 silly decomposeActions postinstall node-gyp-build@4.6.0
76 silly decomposeActions finalize node-gyp-build@4.6.0
77 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json node-gyp-build@4.6.0
78 silly decomposeActions fetch @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
79 silly decomposeActions extract @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
80 silly decomposeActions preinstall @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
81 silly decomposeActions build @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
82 silly decomposeActions install @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
83 silly decomposeActions postinstall @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
84 silly decomposeActions finalize @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
85 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
86 silly decomposeActions fetch serialport@11.0.0
87 silly decomposeActions extract serialport@11.0.0
88 silly decomposeActions preinstall serialport@11.0.0
89 silly decomposeActions build serialport@11.0.0
90 silly decomposeActions install serialport@11.0.0
91 silly decomposeActions postinstall serialport@11.0.0
92 silly decomposeActions finalize serialport@11.0.0
93 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json serialport@11.0.0
94 silly install executeActions
95 silly doSerial global-install 48
96 verbose correctMkdir /home/amin/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
97 verbose lock using /home/amin/.npm/_locks/staging-3420f01a03cc4215.lock for /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.staging
98 silly doParallel extract 6
99 silly extract @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
100 silly extract @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
101 silly extract node-addon-api@6.1.0
102 silly extract node-gyp-build@4.6.0
103 silly extract @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
104 silly extract serialport@11.0.0
105 silly tarball trying node-addon-api@6.1.0 by hash: sha512-+eawOlIgy680F0kBzPUNFhMZGtJ1YmqM6l4+Crf4IkImjYrO/mqPwRMh352g23uIaQKFItcQ64I7KMaJxHgAVA==
106 silly tarball trying node-gyp-build@4.6.0 by hash: sha512-NTZVKn9IylLwUzaKjkas1e4u2DLNcV4rdYagA4PWdPwW87Bi7z+BznyKSRwS/761tV/lzCGXplWsiaMjLqP2zQ==
107 silly tarball trying @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 by hash: sha512-3I1mniVg3osYuIUXxU0jB5AHPsxWmErmc3JC3WfUSlfXsjWMHkHfFzbW9Scuv/z/6DLCJIDyltabRa2FoW2qsQ==
108 silly tarball trying serialport@latest by hash: sha512-bxs3XejQcOHWpzPAaXMhxVRlbem6fjNUrux3ToqrGvFR6BcjOYhqE5CsHOuutv37kmhmnuHrn+/hN+1BpTmaFg==
109 silly tarball trying @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0 by hash: sha512-/uR/yT3jmrcwnl2FJU/2ySvwgo5+XpksDUR4NF/nwTS5i3CcuKS+FKi/tLzy1k8F+rCx5JzpiK+koqPqOUWArA==
110 silly tarball trying @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0 by hash: sha512-0aXJknodcl94W9zSjvU+sLdXiyEG2rqjQmvBWZCr8wJZjWEtv3RgrnYiWq4i2OTOyC8C/oPK8ZjpBjQptRsoJQ==
111 silly extract node-gyp-build@4.6.0 extracted to /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.staging/node-gyp-build-04901aac (35ms)
112 silly extract @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0 extracted to /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.staging/@serialport/parser-readline-2543d4b3 (36ms)
113 silly extract @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0 extracted to /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.staging/@serialport/parser-delimiter-0cf7e480 (37ms)
114 silly extract serialport@latest extracted to /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.staging/serialport-005f68ac (37ms)
115 silly extract node-addon-api@6.1.0 extracted to /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.staging/node-addon-api-b1bfef42 (42ms)
116 silly extract @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 extracted to /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.staging/@serialport/bindings-cpp-99a3c038 (57ms)
117 timing action:extract Completed in 59ms
118 silly doReverseSerial unbuild 48
119 silly doSerial remove 48
120 silly doSerial move 48
121 silly doSerial finalize 48
122 silly finalize /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/node_modules/@serialport/parser-delimiter
123 silly finalize /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/node_modules/@serialport/parser-readline
124 silly finalize /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/node-addon-api
125 silly finalize /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/node-gyp-build
126 silly finalize /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp
127 silly finalize /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/serialport
128 timing action:finalize Completed in 6ms
129 silly doParallel refresh-package-json 6
130 silly refresh-package-json /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/node_modules/@serialport/parser-delimiter
131 silly refresh-package-json /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/node_modules/@serialport/parser-readline
132 silly refresh-package-json /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/node-addon-api
133 silly refresh-package-json /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/node-gyp-build
134 silly refresh-package-json /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp
135 silly refresh-package-json /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/serialport
136 timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 13ms
137 silly doParallel preinstall 6
138 silly preinstall @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
139 info lifecycle @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0~preinstall: @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
140 silly preinstall @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
141 info lifecycle @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0~preinstall: @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
142 silly preinstall node-addon-api@6.1.0
143 info lifecycle node-addon-api@6.1.0~preinstall: node-addon-api@6.1.0
144 silly preinstall node-gyp-build@4.6.0
145 info lifecycle node-gyp-build@4.6.0~preinstall: node-gyp-build@4.6.0
146 silly preinstall @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
147 info lifecycle @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1~preinstall: @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
148 silly preinstall serialport@11.0.0
149 info lifecycle serialport@11.0.0~preinstall: serialport@11.0.0
150 timing action:preinstall Completed in 2ms
151 silly doSerial build 48
152 silly build @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
153 info linkStuff @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
154 silly linkStuff @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0 has /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/node_modules as its parent node_modules
155 silly build @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
156 info linkStuff @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
157 silly linkStuff @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0 has /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/node_modules as its parent node_modules
158 silly build node-addon-api@6.1.0
159 info linkStuff node-addon-api@6.1.0
160 silly linkStuff node-addon-api@6.1.0 has /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules as its parent node_modules
161 silly build node-gyp-build@4.6.0
162 info linkStuff node-gyp-build@4.6.0
163 silly linkStuff node-gyp-build@4.6.0 has /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules as its parent node_modules
164 verbose linkBins [ { 'node-gyp-build': 'bin.js',
164 verbose linkBins     'node-gyp-build-optional': 'optional.js',
164 verbose linkBins     'node-gyp-build-test': 'build-test.js' },
164 verbose linkBins   '/home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.bin',
164 verbose linkBins   false ]
165 silly build @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
166 info linkStuff @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
167 silly linkStuff @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 has /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules as its parent node_modules
168 silly build serialport@11.0.0
169 info linkStuff serialport@11.0.0
170 silly linkStuff serialport@11.0.0 has /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules as its parent node_modules
171 timing action:build Completed in 3ms
172 silly doSerial global-link 48
173 silly doParallel update-linked 0
174 silly doSerial install 48
175 silly install @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
176 info lifecycle @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0~install: @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
177 silly install @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
178 info lifecycle @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0~install: @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
179 silly install node-addon-api@6.1.0
180 info lifecycle node-addon-api@6.1.0~install: node-addon-api@6.1.0
181 silly install node-gyp-build@4.6.0
182 info lifecycle node-gyp-build@4.6.0~install: node-gyp-build@4.6.0
183 silly install @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
184 info lifecycle @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1~install: @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
185 verbose lifecycle @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
186 verbose lifecycle @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1~install: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/node_modules/.bin:/home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
187 verbose lifecycle @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1~install: CWD: /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp
188 silly lifecycle @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1~install: Args: [ '-c', 'node-gyp-build' ]
189 timing audit submit Completed in 376ms
190 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 376ms
191 timing audit body Completed in 1ms
192 silly lifecycle @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
193 info lifecycle @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1~install: Failed to exec install script
194 timing action:install Completed in 3980ms
195 verbose unlock done using /home/amin/.npm/_locks/staging-3420f01a03cc4215.lock for /home/amin/Node/serial-port/node_modules/.staging
196 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 17ms
197 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 6293ms
198 silly saveTree serial-port
198 silly saveTree ├─┬ @serialport/binding-mock@10.2.2
198 silly saveTree │ ├── @serialport/bindings-interface@1.2.2
198 silly saveTree │ └─┬ debug@4.3.4
198 silly saveTree │   └── ms@2.1.2
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/bindings-interface@1.2.2
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-byte-length@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-cctalk@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-delimiter@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-inter-byte-timeout@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-packet-length@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-readline@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-ready@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-regex@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-slip-encoder@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/parser-spacepacket@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── @serialport/stream@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree ├── debug@4.3.4
198 silly saveTree ├── ms@2.1.2
198 silly saveTree └─┬ serialport@11.0.0
198 silly saveTree   └─┬ @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
198 silly saveTree     ├─┬ @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
198 silly saveTree     │ └── @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
198 silly saveTree     ├── node-addon-api@6.1.0
198 silly saveTree     └── node-gyp-build@4.6.0
199 warn notsup Unsupported engine for serialport@11.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
200 warn notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: serialport@11.0.0
201 verbose notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: serialport@11.0.0
201 verbose notsup Required: {"node":">=12.0.0"}
201 verbose notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.4","node":"10.19.0"}
202 warn notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=14.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
203 warn notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
204 verbose notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
204 verbose notsup Required: {"node":">=14.0.0"}
204 verbose notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.4","node":"10.19.0"}
205 warn notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
206 warn notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
207 verbose notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-readline@10.5.0
207 verbose notsup Required: {"node":">=12.0.0"}
207 verbose notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.4","node":"10.19.0"}
208 warn notsup Unsupported engine for @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
209 warn notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
210 verbose notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @serialport/parser-delimiter@10.5.0
210 verbose notsup Required: {"node":">=12.0.0"}
210 verbose notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.4","node":"10.19.0"}
211 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/amin/Node/serial-port/package.json'
212 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
213 warn serial-port No description
214 warn serial-port No repository field.
215 warn serial-port No README data
216 warn serial-port No license field.
217 verbose stack Error: @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 install: `node-gyp-build`
217 verbose stack Exit status 1
217 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
217 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
217 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
217 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
217 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
217 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
218 verbose pkgid @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1
219 verbose cwd /home/amin/Node/serial-port
220 verbose Linux 5.15.0-71-generic
221 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "serialport"
222 verbose node v10.19.0
223 verbose npm  v6.14.4
224 error code ELIFECYCLE
225 error errno 1
226 error @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 install: `node-gyp-build`
226 error Exit status 1
227 error Failed at the @serialport/bindings-cpp@11.0.1 install script.
227 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
228 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with your node version. As the above message says:

wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})

and your system has v10.19.0.

Try using nvm and installing the node version >= 12.0.0.

Here's the reference if you need it: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Thanks I've installed `nvm` switched to the `node version 12.22.12` and it is working now...

Comment: Glad it was helpful.